# How to interpret .pl with mod_perl instead of cgi?

Tags: apache-2.2, perl

I'm now configuring Apache this way:

```
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
```

So that `.pl` will be interpreted as CGI script.

How can I make it run as `mod_perl` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Googling for "howto mod_perl"](http://google.com/search?q=howto%20mod_perl) brings up a [good starters guide](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/method_handlers.html) and a [brief intro with examples](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/635/A_brief_introduction_to_mod_perl_-_Part_1).